# Image as a Repeating Element in Mathematica

Tags: image, wolfram-mathematica, multiple-input

I have been working with `FormFunction` in Mathematica and the function I created takes an image as an input. I am hoping to be able to input multiple images. I found this `RepeatingElement` example that works for Strings but returns an error when I change to image. When I get rid of the parameters there is no error, but it still will not work.

```
FormFunction["field" -> RepeatingElement["String", {2, {1, 5}}]]

FormFunction["field" -> RepeatingElement["Image", {2, {1, 5}}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
CloudDeploy[FormFunction[{"image" -> RepeatingElement["Image"]}, #image &], Permissions -> "Public"]
```